# Let X and Y be non-empty sets, f: X $ \to $ Y a function and F a filter on X...

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, filters

Let X and Y be non-empty sets, f: X $ \to $ Y a function and F a filter on X. Show that $f_*$ (U) = {V $ \subset $ Y: $ f^{- 1} $ [V] $ \in $ U} is a filter on Y. Also show that if F is an ultrafilter over X, then f (U) is an ultrafilter over Y.

---

My attempt

Let some arbitrary set A $\subset$ Y,  and let us show that exactly one of the sets A or Y\A belongs to $f_*$(U).
From the equality $f^{−1}$(Y\A) = X\ $f^{−1}$(A), combined with Lemma(*) applied to U, which gives the fact that exactly one of the sets $f^{−1}$(A) or $f^{−1}$(Y\A) =X\ $f^{−1}$(A) belongs to U.

- Lemma:Let X be  a  non-empty  set,  and  let U be  a  filter  on X.The following are equivalent:
  (i)U is an ultrafilter.
  (ii)For  any  subsets A $\subset$ X,  it  follows  that  either A or X\A belongs  to U,but not both.

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: That is, you prove only the last part?

Comment: You need say $f(f^{-1}(A))=A\in f(U)$ or $f(f^{-1}$(Y\A)=Y\A$\in f(U)$ to complete the statement.

Comment: @Mars: That is not necessary. Andre has shown that exactly one of $f^{-1}[A]$ and $f^{-1}[Y\setminus A]$ is in $U$, which by definition means that exactly one of $A$ and $Y\setminus A$ is in $f_*(U)$ and hence that $f_*(U)$ is an ultrafilter on $Y$ (assuming that he’s already proved that it’s a filter).

Comment: This is correct for the second part of the question. Have you already shown that $f_*(F)$ is a filter on $Y$ if $F$ is a filter on $X$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I already show that part and thanks for everyone's feedback.